# The number $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n^2}}$ is transcendental

Tags: number-theory, special-functions, transcendental-numbers

> Prove that the number:
>   $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n^2}}$$
>   is transcendental.

*I don't have a direct proof but a round one.* The series can be expressed in terms of $\vartheta_3$ which is one of the theta Jacobi functions. More specifically,

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n^2}}=\vartheta_{3} \left (\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

From the theory of the Jacobi function we know that for $|q|<1$ the series converges and the number is transcedental.

*Any other direct proof?*

Comment: Isn't this just Liouville's original transcendental number, or essentially so?

Comment: I have no idea about Liouville's original transcedental number.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: That has 1's in factorial-indexed digits, not square-indexed digits.

Comment: Your constant is a [Liouville number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number). “In 1844, Joseph Liouville showed that all Liouville numbers are transcendental, thus establishing the existence of transcendental numbers for the first time.”

Comment: The title of this question should be more explicit. How about, "Is there a direct proof that the number … is trancendental?"

Comment: "from the theory of the Jacobi function we know that for $|q| < 1$ the series converges and the number is transcendental" -- certainly the value is not transcendental for all $|q| < 1$. What theorem are you citing?

Comment: I think it is not a Liouville number, the "$1$'s" are not sparse enough.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Aren't they? I was trying to decide that,  Cut the sum at $k$.  Then the error is less than $\frac {1}{2^{(k+1)^2}-1}$.  So say the thing had degree k.  The denominator of your rational approximation is $\frac {1}{2^{k^2}}$ so you are too close, by a factor that grows like $2^k$.  Liouville won't let that factor grows that fast, right?  He insists on a constant.

Comment: I think the usual short argument for the transcendence of Liouville numbers breaks down, and that the transcendence degree is finite.

Comment: Oh, maybe "Liouville number" means something more precise than I realized (just gliding over the fact that I don't know what transcendence degree means). Do you agree that the number is transcendental for the reason I gave?  (to be clear, I am not at all confident of my argument. I have forgotten how the theorem works).

Comment: @hunter Reading a book about special functions when theory of theta jacobi is developed at the end of it, there is this theorem. Of course I have no proof but since it is mentioned well... you take it for granted ... !!

Comment: OK, I am little lost here. Is it or is it not a Liouville number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very similar question has been answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55397/is-this-number-already-known-to-be-transcendental-is-there-a-survey-about-up-to). Basically, it's known that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{n^2}$$

is transcendental if $q$ is algebraic and $0<|q|<1$. Thus, taking $q=\frac12$, we see

$$\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac12\right)^{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^{n^2}}$$

is transcendental, and thus, your constant is
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac1{2^{n^2}}&=\left(\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac1{2^{n^2}}\right)+1+\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{2^{n^2}}\right)\\
&=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{2^{n^2}}\right)+1+\alpha\\
&=2\alpha+1
\end{align}

so yes, your number is transcendental.

Comment: Yeah. I was already aware of that. You are using the Jacobi Theta functions, that is $\vartheta_3(1/2,0)$. Anyway (+1)